# SSL Client Auth for Apache Forward Proxy

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I'm trying to authenticate a specific user for whom I've issued a certificate to authenticate to my web proxy using the mentioned certificate.
I think I've tried almost 20 combinations of the following options and nothing seems to work for me. In the apache docs pages all the example for ssl client auth are often based on `<Location>`directive. My case is never mentioned and at this point I'm wondering if it is possible at all:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

ProxyRequests On
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/myca/ca.cer

<Proxy "*">
    SSLVerifyClient Require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLOptions  +FakeBasicAuth +StrictRequire
    SSLRequire ( %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)-/   \
        and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "MyComp"       \
        and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "IT"           \
        and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} eq "my@email.com")
</Proxy>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

With the above configuration the proxy works but doesn't ask for authentication, everybody can use it.

- I've tried to put `SSLVerifyClient Require` outside the `Proxy`directive and nothing change
- I've removed `SSLRequire` and nothing change
- I've removed `SSLOptions` and nothing change
- I've added the `Require ssl-verify-client` within the `Proxy`directive and I get a 403 error. Adding the certificate into the browser doesn't change anything.

I've tried a similar configuration within a simple `<Location />`directive as showed in apache examples and it works indeed. But I can't solve it for my proxy case.